# remove selection from select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a select box, from which I want to remove selected choice with jquery. 
Please advise me how I can make this working: 
this is the code for the markup:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Names)
            {
                <div>                        
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <select multiple id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>  
                    </div>
                    <div>  
                    <a href="#" id="remove">Remove selection</a>  
                    </div>  
                </div>
            }
```

There are three select boxes and for each one I need to add a hyperlink for removing selection. 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: IDs must be unique, so your code will not work if it runs in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should change `id="remove"` to `class="remove"` since you will have multiple of these elements and it's not valid HTML to have the same ID used multiple times.

You can use jQuery to select the anchor tags and bind an event handler that removes the anchor's parent element (which also contains the `<select>` elements):

```
$(function () {
    $('.remove').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7SueN/2/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

If you want to only remove the `<select>` element associated with each link you can target it for removal:

```
$(function () {
    $('.remove').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('select').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7SueN/1/

### Update

I just re-read your question and if you want to remove the selected index of the select when the link is pressed:

```
$(function () {
    $('.remove').on('click', function () {
        
        var $select = $(this).parent().parent().find('select');
        $select.children().filter(':selected').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7SueN/

Comment: Thanks Jasper, yes the update did the thing. Wow, Jquery is really powerful tool, I need to get more jquery knowledge. Thanks everyone else for your comments too.

Comment: @Laziale Feel free to accept this answer and/or up-vote if you found the information useful :).

Answer (score 1):

### Working Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GFdP6/1/

### Markup

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Names)
{
   <div class="listContainer">                        
        <div class="editor-field">
           <select multiple id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>  
        </div>
        <div>  
           <a href="#" class="remove">Remove selection</a>  
        </div>  
   </div>
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('.remove').click(function(){    
    $(this).closest('.listContainer').find('select').find(':selected').remove();
});
```

Comment: `.closest()` only looks in the element's ancestors: `Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.`. So `$(this).closest('select')` won't ever select anything given the HTML structure.

Comment: Ok, you're getting somewhere :). that will find the first `div` ancestor element, which only contains the `<a>` element. You will need another `.closest('div')` to get an ancestor of the `<select>` element: `$(this).closest('div').closest('div')`. ..up-vote seems strange, this code won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/7SueN/3/

Comment: Ok, but you should note in your answer that you changed the structure of the HTML, because if the OP doesn't make the same changes to the HTML structure then it won't work.

Comment: The fiddle has the same structure now. So there's no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove the selection or the selected elements?

As the removal of the elements has been answered, in the case it's just the selection:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){    
  $(this).closest('select').children().is(':selected').prop("selected",null);
});
```

EDIT:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){    
  $(this).parent().prev().find('option:selected').prop("selected",null);
});
```

Comment: `.closest()` only looks in the element's ancestors: `Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.`. So `$(this).closest('select')` won't ever select anything given the HTML structure.

Comment: Closer :). But the `<a>` element doesn't have any siblings. You could get the parent of the `<a>` element, then find it's sibling, then get the `<select>` element, and finally the selected `<option>` elements: `$(this).parent().prev().children().children(':selected')`.